# Accessing Number value of one class in other static class

Tags: java

Accessing the `FileType` values in converterfactory. I have a class named `FileType`:

```
public final class FileType 
{

    public static final FileType VALUES[]; 
    public static final FileType WORD;

    static 
    {
        WORD= new FileType("WORD", 0);
        VALUES = (new FileType[] { WORD});
    }

    public static final FileType[] values()
    {
        return (FileType[])VALUES.clone();
    }

    String s;
    int i;

    private FileType(String msofficedoC, int i) {
        this.s= msofficedoC;
        this.i=i;
    }
}
```

I have a another class `ConverterFactory` in which I want to access the number of `MSOFFICEDOC` as `0` so I have `_cls1` class.

```
static class cls1
{
    static final int SwitchMapfile2xliff4jFileType[];

    static 
    {
        SwitchMapfiletoxliffFileType = new int[FileType.values().length];

        try
        {
            SwitchMapfiletoxliffFileType[FileType.WORD.ordinal()] = 1;

        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldError nosuchfielderror) { }
    }
}
```

In `FileType.WORD.ordinal()` it is giving an error but I want to access `FileType.WORD` value in switch case

```
switch(cls1.SwitchMapfiletoxliffFileType[filetype.i]) 
{
    case 1:
}
```

It is giving an exception

> `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"`
>
> `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`

please give me some suggestion this .
Thank you in advanced

Comment: Do you really name variables and classes like this?... May the Flying Spaghetti Monster bless those, who work with your code.

Comment: and the questions is?

Comment: Let me tell you, you have the worst choice of classes and variables names. I am still confused between where $ is starting and where $ is ending. Also where have you defined filetype in _cls1.

Is it that you have "decompiled" some class?

Comment: is this java? Please use better variable names and classnames and then repost the code as I dont understand anything here.

Comment: Some of your code seems to be out of the classes, please give your outer class as well, or put the code to its rightful place.

Comment: I am extremly sorry about my naming convention.

Comment: Please help me it is giving an error on SwitchMapfiletoxliffFileType = new int[FileType.values().length];

Comment: @Aditya Please update your code, because this makes no sense. Your VALUES variable has never been declared. And give us the error message you receive, it'll help us in helping you.

Comment: @Michaël Benjamin Saerens  sir i updated the code and exception

Comment: Sweet baby Jesus; read the naming conventions.

Comment: where the hell have you defined the `FileType.WORD`?? it's not shown in any piece of your code!

Comment: @Chris anything wrong in my code please tell me i will correct it with your support.

Comment: @Aditya your code is not showing where have you defined the `FileType.WORD` value. Your current code shouldn't compile.

Comment: @Aditya Your FileType doesn't have an ordinal() method. Please re-read your own code and make sure it's functional and correct!

Comment: Could you provide a stack trace rather than just ExceptionInInitializerError. That error "Signals that an unexpected exception has occurred in a static initializer" (from the javadoc). Maybe you could reconsider the static initializers and have some kind of singleton.

Comment: @Aditya now it'd be great if you posted the whole stacktrace (the complete description of the exception)

Comment: @Michaël Benjamin Saerens yes sir my problem is ordinal() instead of this how i can access the value of class FileType in that i have static final variables like Word,PPT,etc i posted only one. 
In SwitchMapfiletoxliffFileType[FileType.WORD.ordinal()] = 1;
if i select Word in my tool of drop downlist then the that 0 value should come in switch condition like

 Switch(0)
and then i have case 0.which contain function that i need to call but i am getting an exception in SwitchMapfiletoxliffFileType[FileType.WORD.ordinal()] = 1;

so what i need to do?

Comment: @Aditya The problem now is that the code that you've provided us, doesn't have an ordinal() method. This code cannot compile.